# Lost reputation when resetting my password

Tags: support, user-accounts

I forgot my Stack Overflow password. When I reset it I lost all my reputation and badges.

Does resetting my password mean that you want to reset your account and open a new one?

After resetting I found that Stack Overflow duplicated my account and conserved the same username and the same avatar.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2375535/nomade) is your old account. Probably you have changed your email id. You can merge your both accounts. See here [how to merge?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232/187824).

Answer (score 6):

As hims056 points out in his comment, you ended up creating a new account.

You now have two accounts. Your old one:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/2375535/nomade

and your new one:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/2795011/nomade

Go to the [Contact page](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) and select the "I need to merge user profiles" option.

Comment: thanks for the reply ChrisF. just when i put my profiles links which one will be keeped and which one will be deleted because i want to keep my older account

Comment: @nomade - Both will be *merged*. So if you have contributed from both, your contributions will be merged in your old account. So you don't need to worry. :)

Comment: @nomade The team will be able to tell which is the older account and will merge the newer on into that. The form has two places for the profile links so add the new one to the "other" field. You can also add a comment to make things clear.

Comment: yeah ! just I was waiting for the confirmation e-mail from Stackoverflow team .. i did not receive it until this moment ! i don't know if they will ask me for the pass word of the older account or not !?